# Stuck on one Google account

Tags: support, accounts, google

I have two Google accounts: x@gmail.com and y@gmail.com. I am happily registered on SE with y@gmail.com - somehow IE has remembered all this and so I am asking this question via that login. BUT - I rarely use IE and on Firefox, when I attempt to log in to SE via a Google account I am *always* prompted to create a *new* account with the x@gmail account! 
I don't want to create a new account via x@ and simply want to select the y@ account and log in - as is now automated in IE.

Why can't I do this in FF and how do I stop FF (or SE) forever prompting via only the x@ account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All Stack Exchange does is ask Google to authenticate you, and it is Google that tells Stack Exchange you are using `x@gmail.com`.

You need to go and log out of `x@gmail.com` *over on Google*, and log in as `y@gmail.com` instead.

Comment: Thank you - I had not realised that I was logged in and/or that being so would have this effect. Yet another reason to dislike the stay-logged-in pressure from Google.